# Multilingual MVC Application With WEB API And Angularjs/i18n

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am working in mvc application with Angular js.i wanted to implement Angularjs/i18n in my application.but i have gone through with more tutorial but i didn't get any good explored tutorial where we can change date control,currency or so on.please let me know if you have any sample demo application.i have tried below implementation

```
var app = angular.module('at', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

app.config(function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    TITLE: 'Hello',
    FOO: 'This is a paragraph.',
    BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'english',
    BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'german'
  });
  $translateProvider.translations('de', {
    TITLE: 'Hallo',
    FOO: 'Dies ist ein Paragraph.',
    BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'englisch',
    BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'deutsch'
  });
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $translate) {
  $scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {
    $translate.use(key);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter. Create a directive to handle all your i18n transformation.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date